# Keyboard hooks can cause input lag？

Tags: c#, dll, hook

I use hooks in C# code to capture user keyboard input.
code show as below：

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelHookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
    {
        return SetWindowsHookEx(idHook, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
    }
```

And the proc is my processing function. This function will be called whenever there is a key input. The Code like this:

```
private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && (wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        // do something
    }
    if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
    {
        // do something
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The problem now is that when the CPU occupancy rate of my computer is high, the keyboard input will lag behind. That is, I keep pressing the A key, and when I release the keyboard, it is still typing.

I think it is, assuming that 10 A keys are entered, but due to the high CPU usage, I released the keys when only the 5th key was processed, and the computer continued to process the remaining 5 keys, which caused this lag.

So is my guess correct? Is there any way to solve this problem here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't use keyboard hooks unless you absolutely know what you're doing (and you _really_ shouldn't write them in a language with non-deterministic program execution like C#/.NET). [Instead, you should use the Win32 Raw Input API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input): you can still capture low-level keyboard (and mouse and USB/HID, and more) without affecting other applications and it's fine to use with C#/.NET, if a little hairy because C# is still unergonomic for consuming C APIs (fun-fact: Raw Input is also effectively the successor to DirectInput and XInput).

Comment: Yes, Dai. I think I should use the keyboard hook. Because I need to monitor user input outside the screen. I am looking at win32 raw input api. I seem to have tried to use these in C# before, I picked it up and tried again.

Comment: What do you mean by "input outside the screen"?  Raw Input does not need a `hWnd`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about what I mean. That is, my software needs to get the user's input on other interfaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "other interfaces"? ("_Human Interfaces_", Graphical User Interfaces? Application Programming Interfaces?) - well, my question is irrelevant because Raw Input is more than capable of what you're after - you just need to have another try at it.

Comment: At a complete guess, your code is too complex and slow and is causing keyboard input to lag. But we don't know without seeing your callback code

Comment: @Dai I mean, I need to get keyboard input even when the focus is not on my software. For example, some of his input in Chrome.

Comment: Please show your full code in your question, not as a comment. You can and should still use Raw Input. [Quote from docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevice) *`RIDEV_INPUTSINK` If set, this enables the caller to receive the input even when the caller is not in the foreground. Note that hwndTarget must be specified.*

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, there is a lot of judgment logic in my callback function. I had the same guess as you before. I tried to hide all the judgments and just return directly. But the problem still exists, so I am also very confused.

Comment: @Charlieface Added some related callback codes, which are too much to be completely pasted. There are probably more than a dozen judgment logics, which are mainly used to judge whether there is an input combination key (for example, shift + a)

Comment: @Dai I've tried a few things, and they haven't worked. I believe your usage applies to C# Form development, right? I'm currently developing in Unity, so I can't get through this method. Am I not doing it the right way or do I have to continue using hook?

Comment: What would be in one of those `do something` sections?

Comment: Please update your question to include what is discussed in the comments.  How did determined if the lag is due to the hook or your "judegment code"?  Can you replicate the issue with a simpler application, or when there is no complex logic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.